# Convert python JSON data into JavaScript Array Variable

Tags: python

I am working under python now i have a JSON value as given below,

```
[
   [
    u'November',
    {
      u'fund': 0.0,
      u'fund_position': [
        {
          u'closing_balance': -1200.0,
          u'id': 463,
          u'name': u'HDFC bank coimbatore',
          u'group_name': u'Bank Account'
    },
    {
      u'closing_balance': 0.0,
      u'id': 97,
      u'name': u'Cash In Hand',
      u'group_name': u'Cash in Hand'
    },
    {
      u'closing_balance': 0.0,
      u'id': 488,
      u'name': u'Cash LEdger add',
      u'group_name': u'Cash in Hand'
    },
    {
          u'closing_balance': 1200.0,
          u'id': 570,
          u'name': u'Carrom',
          u'group_name': u'Cash in Hand'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

and i wanted to  convert this as a javascript array.  how to achieve this?
I have tried this,
`$.map(JSON.parse({{ response_data }}), function(el) { return el })`
but it wont work it through some error
`Unexpected token u in JSON at position 2`

OR tell me how to remove the prefix 'u' on each field

thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever that is, it's not valid JSON

Comment: yes i think i should remove the jquery or javascript tags

Comment: yes found the answer by adding json.dumps in python module ..thanks and sorry for disturbed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a valid JSON string from a Python dictionary you'd have to use the `json` package. To achieve the same "pretty printed" effect, use the parameter `indent`.

```
import json

print(json.dumps(response_data, indent=4))
```